# replace x, y in arraylist of arraylists in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to figure out how to replace a specific index in a arraylist of arraylists

The only stuff I've been able to find so far is how to just get the index with .get(x).get(y)
I'm having no real luck with google at the moment, so I figured I'd finally make a post about it. Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `set(int index, E o)`. See [ArrayList#set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
.get(x).set(y, value);
```

Comment: I tried doing that and I was getting an array index out of bounds. I tried .get(0).set(3, Title);    Timer being a String variable. the array is 2 x 27, so I'm not getting why it's saying out of bounds. I'll mess with it some more and get back to you. Maybe I made a mistake

Comment: works great, that was just a mistake, 3> 2 duh. my brain is practically shut off at the moment. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> s = . . .;
s.get(3).set(4, "new value");
```

Answer (score 0):

As @peeskillet suggest a best solution..

But check this core java code if it have some sense.

```
String arrayList[] = {....your array content...};

for (String token : arrayList) {
         token = token.replace("x", "replaceanythings");
         token = token.replace("y", "replaceanythings");
        }
```